# Looping through tables and querying each of them in two different schemas

Tags: sql, loops, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a script that I run for a particular table to compare, for now just a simple `COUNT(*)` on two different schemas (doing a migration).

Here's what it looks like:

```sql
SET table_name = 'users';
SET prod_result = 0;
SET dev_result = 0;

USE SCHEMA db.base;

SET prod_result = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM IDENTIFIER($table_name));

USE SCHEMA db_dev.test_base;

SET dev_result = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM IDENTIFIER($table_name));

SELECT
  $prod_result,
  $dev_result
```

It works well but I am trying to find a way I could run this for all tables I want. I have been trying cursors like this:

```sql
DECLARE
  results RESULTSET DEFAULT(SELECT table_name FROM db.information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'BASE');
  c1 CURSOR FOR results;

FOR record in c1 DO
  SELECT record
END FOR;
```

But I'm actually getting an error by `DECLARE` `Statement expected, got Decalre` and I can't work out why.

[image]

Comment: Please add the error message to your question

Comment: Thanks, forgot to add the screenshot.. it's there now

Comment: DECLARE statement should come before any other code in PL/SQL. Additionally, you need to declare the cursor before you can use it.
How is the relationship of the two code snippets?

Comment: Where I have `SELECT record` is where I wanted to use the code from the top and then, somehow, keep the results concatenated (or in array) to display after the cursor

Comment: I thinkyou need to restructure the code to have the DECLARE at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

*(I didn't test this code, but as i can't have formatted text in a comment, i try a full-fledged Answer)*

The DECLARE statement should come before any other code in PL/SQL. And you need to declare the cursor before you can use it.
That said, here is some untested code, which may not work, but you get the direction. So you start like this:

```
-- Declare variables
DECLARE table_name STRING;
DECLARE prod_result INT64;
DECLARE dev_result INT64;

-- Declare a cursor to fetch table names
DECLARE
  CURSOR c1 IS 
    SELECT table_name 
    FROM db.information_schema.tables 
    WHERE table_schema = 'BASE';
  
  table_name VARCHAR(255);
  prod_result INT;
  dev_result INT;
BEGIN
  FOR table_rec IN c1 LOOP
    table_name := table_rec.table_name;

    -- and then do everything you need
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Got the point?

Comment: How do I use the `table_name` within the loop? `Session variable $table_name doesn't exist` appears when I move the code within the loop. Do I use it differently then `IDENTIFIER($table_name)`?

Comment: Have a look at the update in my answer.
Works better now?

Comment: I don't think `CURSOR c1 IS` is right syntax for Snowflake. When I change it to `DECLARE CURSOR c1 FOR SELECT` I get an error `unexpected CURSOR`. If I try to run your code I get `unexpected c1` and `unexpected IS`